# Packages from PPA do not appear in `apt search`

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa

On an Ubuntu 18.04 machine, I've added the `deadsnakes` PPA to install Python3.10 with `sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`. It does so without complaints. `sudo -E apt update` works as well and, among others, it prints the line

```
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
```

However, once this is done, `apt search python3.10` only gives me:

```
postgresql-plpython3-10/bionic-updates,bionic-security 10.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
  PL/Python 3 procedural language for PostgreSQL 10
```

In fact, I can only find python3.6, python3.7 and python3.8 in `apt search`.